# For In loop, why property value can't be accessed through obj.property?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

```
var ni = {'hello': 23, 'he':'h', hao: 45};
for( var propertyName in ni) {
    console.log(ni[propertyName])  //23,'h',45
    console.log(ni.propertyName)   // undefined 3 times?
}
```

what is the reason ni.propertyName doesn't work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ni.propertyName` is equivalent to `ni["propertyName"]`: it gets the value of a property literally named `"propertyName"`. `ni[propertyName]` on the other hand uses your `propertyName` variable for the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

`ni.propertyName` is static code that references the property named *`propertyName`* in `ni` (which does not exist). Note this is equivalent to `ni["propertyName"]`.

`ni[propertyName]` dynamically indexes into `ni` to find the property named with the *value of `propertyName`*.